# I don't understand what this question is asking and how to show it/prove it$

Tags: convergence-divergence, recursive-algorithms

Given the sequence $T_n$ where $T_1 = 0, T_2 = 1, T_3 = 1$ and $T_n = T_{n-1} + T_{n-2} + T_{n-3}$ for $n >= 3$. Find what the ratio of consecutive terms, $\frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}$ is converging to.

So I think the wording for this problem is not great, but I don't really know what it is asking and what to do to show it. Is it like a limit? A sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_n + T_{n-1} + T_{n-2}}{T_n}$. If the sequence $\frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}$ converges, set $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n} = L$.

Then:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{T_{n}}{T_{n-1}} = \frac{1}{L}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{T_{n-2}}{T_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{T_{n-2}}{T_n} \frac{T_{n-1}}{T_{n-1}} = \frac{1}{L^2}$. This comes from basic properties of limits, such as the product of two converging sequences converges to the product of their limits. From this, we have:

$$L = 1 + \frac{1}{L} + \frac{1}{L^2} \Rightarrow L^3 = L^2 + L + 1$$
The only real solution to this polynomial is $L = \frac{1}{3} (1 + \sqrt[3]{19 - 3 \sqrt{33}} + \sqrt[3]{19 + 3 \sqrt{33}} )$ - which is the answer to your problem.

Comment: this is perfect thank you! just checking my estimates your answer looks about right - I'm getting about 5/3

Comment: could you explain why the 1/L holds true and why you used Tn-1 and not n+1?

Comment: If I have a converging sequence $a_n$, then all its subsequences $b_n = a_{n_k}$, $k, n_k \in \mathbb{N}$, converges to the same limit as $a_n$. In particular, $b_n = a_{n + p}$, where $p$ is a fixed positive integer.

Comment: OH I see, so even Tn-1 when n goes to inf will be the same

Comment: In other words, where you start in a convergent sequence does not matter, for after a finite number of terms, you can be as near the limit as you want - if you want, try proving it with $\epsilon$.

Comment: I see, thank you so much this is very helpful

Comment: It doesn't matter if the roots are real or not.  The dominant one will be the one of largest absolute value.  In this case the real root is the one of largest absolute value.

Comment: also how do you prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{T_{n-1}}{T_{n}} = \frac{1}{L}$ and then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{T_{n-2}}{T_{n-1}} = \frac{1}{L}$

Answer (score 1):

You have been given a [linear homogeneous recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).  Can you see that you have enough information to calculate $T_n$ for any $n$ by stepping up from below?.  For example, $T_4=T_3+T_2+T_1=1+1+0=2$  You can program this into a spreadsheet easily with copy down and find a numeric approximation.  You are expected to find the characteristic polynomial and then find its greatest root.  That will be your answer.  Read the linked article, or your text, to find out why.

Comment: I see, Thank you for the hint

Comment: The exact form is rather a mess, coming from a cubic.  I don't know if you are being asked for the exact form or a numeric approximation.

Comment: so I am taking the limit as n approaches zero, hmm

Comment: wait so I have to do all that stuff on the solve, my god that is a lot

Comment: You are taking the limit as $n$ approaches infinity, not zero.

Comment: my bad you are right

Comment: hmm I am guessing it is inbetween 2 and 1.5 (based off some calculations of points), but I have no idea to show where it should be

Comment: Ok using matlab I'm getting about 5/3, but I have no idea how to prove it.