# How to show that this specific limit exists in this proof?

Tags: limits, proof-explanation, recursive-algorithms

Given the sequence $T_n$ where $T_1 = 0, T_2 = 1, T_3 = 1$ and $T_n = T_{n-1} + T_{n-2} + T_{n-3}$ for $n >= 3$. Find what the ratio of consecutive terms, $\frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}$ is converging to.

I already have figured out what the ratio is converging to:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}$$}
Now, we first assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}$ exists and converges at a finite value. Let's say that:
$$A = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{T_{n} + T_{n-1} + T_{n-2}}{T_n}$$
Due to properties of limits, we can individually find each limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{T_{n} + T_{n-1} + T_{n-2}}{T_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_{n}}{T_n} + \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_{n-1}}{T_n} + \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_{n-2}}{T_n}$$
{Now let's solve each individual limit.}
$$\begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_{n}}{T_n} &= 1\\
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_{n-1}}{T_n} &= \frac{1}{A}\\
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_{n-2}}{T_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ T_{n-2}  T_{n-1} }{ T_n  T_{n-1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_{n-2}}{T_{n-1}} \cdot \frac{T_{n-1}}{T_{n}} &= \frac{1}{A^2}
 \end{align}
$$
Substitute all our identities into our original equation:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n} = A &= 1 + \frac{1}{A} + \frac{1}{A^2}\\
    A^3 &= A^2 + A + 1\\
    A &= \frac{1}{3}(1 + \sqrt[3]{19 -3\sqrt{33}} + \sqrt[3]{19 + 3\sqrt{33}})\\
    A &\approx 1.839286755\ldots
    \end{align}
$$
How do I prove my underlying assumption that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}$ converges and exists?
Also as another side question: Why does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_{n-1}}{T_n} = \frac{1}{A}$? Same with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_{n-2}}{T_{n-1}} = \frac{1}{A}$?

Link to answer of the original question: [I don't understand what this question is asking and how to show it/prove it$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690308/i-dont-understand-what-this-question-is-asking-and-how-to-show-it-prove-it/2690336?noredirect=1#comment5556388_2690336)

Comment: Exact solution must be obtained, see my hint below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3-x^2-x-1.$ The equation $f(x)=0$ has $3$ complex solutions $x_1,x_2,x_3$ with $x_1\in \Bbb R$ and $1<x_1<2$ and where $x_2,x_3$ are non-real complex conjugates of each other.

And $1=x_1x_2x_3=x_1|x_2|^2$ so $x_1>1>|x_2|=|x_3|.$

(i). If $A,B,C$ are constants and $V_n=Ax_1^n+Bx_2^n+Cx_3^n$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ then $V_{n+3}=V_{n+2}+V_{n+1}+V_n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N.$

(ii). Given any values  $T_1,T_2,T_3,$ there exist a unique $(A,B,C)$ such that $Ax_1^j+Bx_2^j+Cx_3^j=T_j$ for $j\in \{1,2,3\}.$ Then by induction on $n\geq 3$, if $T_n$ satisfies the recursion formula,  we have $T_n=Ax_1^n+Bx_2^n+Cx_3^n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N.$

(iii). Therefore by (i) and (ii), with $T_1=0, T_2=1,T_3=1,$ there exists $(A,B,C)$ such that $T_n=Ax_1^n+Bx_2^n +Cx_3^n$ for all n\in \Bbb N.

And $A\ne 0.$ Because  $|x_2|=|x_3|<1$ so $|Bx_2^n+Cx_3^n|\to 0$ as $x\to \infty,$ but $|T_n|=|Ax_1^n+Bx_2^n+Cx_3^n|\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty.$

So $\frac {T_{n+1}}{T_n}=$ $x_1\cdot \frac {   1+BA^{-1}(x_2/x_1)^{n+1}   +CA^{-1}(x_3/x_1)^{n+1}   }   {  1+   BA^{-1}(x_2/x_1)^n +   CA^{-1}(x_3/x_1)^n   }.$

Since $|x_2/x_1|=|x_3/x_1|<1,$ therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {T_{n+1}}{T_n}=x_1\approx 1.839287, $ the real-number solution of $x^3=x^2+x+1.$

Comment: thank you! this is good reasoning as to why.

Comment: Since $T_n\in \Bbb R$ for all $n,$ the values  $B,C$ are complex conjugates of each other.

Comment: Thank u. The function $f(x)$ is called the associated, or characteristic, polynomial, of the recurrence. It gets a little more complicated when the polynomial has a repeated root.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The proof seems not perfect. And why then $T_2=T_3=1$?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov . In the Q we have $T_2=T_3=1.$

Answer (score 1):

$$T_n = T_{n-1} + T_{n-2} + T_{n-3}$$

$$T_1 = 0, T_2 = 1, T_3 = 1$$

Note that the terms are growing without bound because $a_{n+1}>a_n +1$ for $  n\ge 2 $

$$0,1,1,2,4,7,13,24,....$$

Thus you are dealing with a strictly  increasing sequence which goes to infinity.

Comment: but what about $\frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}$?

Comment: It goes to$ \frac {\infty }{\infty }$ in limits.

Comment: Isn't that an indeterminate form?

Comment: That is the problem with the ratio test .

Comment: So is there no way of showing that it converges?

Comment: No, even the fake ratio test shows the ratio goes to a limit of 1.83.. which is greater than 1. r

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Looking for solution in the form of
$$T_n = e^{an},$$
one can obtain the characteristic equation
$$z^3-z^2-z-1 = 0$$
[with the known roots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E3-z%5E2-z-1%3D0).

That leads to the solution in the form of
$$T_n = C_0A^n + C_1B^ne^{n\varphi}+C_2B_ne^{-n\varphi},$$
wherein
$$T_0=0,\quad T_1=T_2=1.$$